# Configuration of reCAPTCHA for Keycloak via CLI

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is there a way to configure reCAPTCHA via the CLI for a Keycloak standalone installation? To be more precise, is it possible to carry out all the steps described [here in the Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_recaptcha) with the help of `kcadm.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resource).

The first step is to get an admin token, so that one can call the Rest API:

```
curl    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
        -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
        -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
        -d "grant_type=password" \
        https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

You will get a `json response` with the admin token. Extract the **access token** from that response (lets called `$ACCESS_TOKEN`).

Now, we need to get the list of all executions linked to the registration flow:

```
curl  -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/authentication/flows/registration/executions \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From that `json response`, extract the `id` of the `"providerId=registration-recaptcha-action"`. Lets call that `id`, `$ID_RECAPTCHA`.

Next make the reCaptcha required at the registration:

```
CAPTCHA_DATA='{"id":"$ID_RECAPTCHA","requirement":"REQUIRED","providerId":"registration-recaptcha-action"}'

curl -X PUT https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/authentication/flows/registration/executions \
                            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                            -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"\
                            -d "$JSON_DATA"
```

Finally, to configure your own captcha:

```
CONFIG_DATA='{"config":{"site.key":"<YOUR SITE KEY>","secret":"<YOUR SECRET>","useRecaptchaNet":"<True or False>"},"alias":"<The CAPTCHA ALIAS>"}'

curl -X POST https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/authentication/executions/$ID_RECAPTCHA/config \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"\
```

Next, the best thing is to automatize this process with, for instance, some bash scripts.